# Using group policy migration table does not catch all occurrences

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, gpo

I'm trying to use the `Group Policy Migration Table Editor` to make a conversion table for my import job...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And as you can see below, the results are somewhat positive but I can't seem to get it to account for all occurrences in the policy.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?